# Google maps on android no gms

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having a problem rendering google maps.

I am using a zebra device with No GMS (Google mobile services) and after exectuing the script it is showing me a blank page. Otherwise on GMS devices works perfectly.

```
function loadGoogle() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.....';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors or information on your Javascript console?

Comment: Hi namelivia, no there where no errors on the console...

Answer (score 0):

After long ours of googling out everything I found that the problem was not in google api, it was the rendering that was not triggering so I rerendered the page after the execution of the function